# Unexpected result when use swap function to swap two references in Java

Tags: java

I have two references, reference a point to object a, reference b point to object b, then I called a swap function to try to let a point to object b, b point to object a, it is swapped in the swap function, but result in main function didn't change. So what I should do?

The swap function:

```
private void swap(Stack<TreeNode> a, Stack<TreeNode> b) {
    Stack<TreeNode> temp = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Java is pass by value. Those are keywords, look them up.

Comment: Q: it is swapped in the swap function, but result in main function didn't change?  A: [Does Java pass by reference or by value?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

Comment: Nothing changed because `a`, `b` and `temp` are all within the scope of `swap`. It has no impact on the caller.

Comment: But, you can modify internals of `a` and `b` and this is visible in caller scope :)

Comment: The whole method is eligible to be optimized by the JIT compiler to nothhingness.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: work at not working. My bad, comment deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of the swap is local to the method, it won't have any effect once the method returns to its calling point - you're simply swapping local variables. When the method got invoked, a copy of a  reference to the objects got passed, not the actual objects themselves.

Java has pass-by-value semantics, in the case of objects being passed as parameters to a method that means that a copy of the reference is passed. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/201359) for an example.

Also notice that the object references existing *before* calling the method, and the references existing *inside* the method as parameters are actually pointing to the same object, so any modifications to the object's contents you do inside a method *will* remain in place once the method returns.

Comment: @paulsm4 hmmm, yes. If you pass, say, an empty list, and add elements to it inside a method, after the method returns the list _will_ contain those objects.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing local parameters, not the acutal contents of those references. One solution is to modify the instances you're sending. E.g.

```
private boolean swap(Stack<TreeNode> a, Stack<TreeNode> b)
{
    if(a == null || b == null) return false;
    Stack<TreeNode> temp = new Stack<>();
    while(!a.empty()) temp.add(a.pop());
    while(!b.empty()) a.add(0, b.pop());
    while(!temp.empty()) b.add(temp.pop()); 
    return true;   
}
```